# Is it correct to use the phrase "Dreaming on another love"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it correct to use the phrase "Dreaming on another love"?

I am aware that the most often used phrase would be "Dreaming of another love", however I wonder if one can say "Dreaming on a star" or "Dreaming on a world" Can one also say "Dreaming on another love"?

I am writing a song & this would be of great help.

Thank you

Comment: Song lyrics do not have to follow proper grammar, essentially you can do whatever works best for the rhythm, rhyme, or meaning you want to convey.

Comment: It's valid poetic language.  Not normal conversational English.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, the phrase makes sense, I immediately know what you mean even if it is a slight odd way to put it.